# SQL with non-existing column in where cause can be executed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here's my SQL

```
select * 
from TableA 
where colA1 in (select colA1 from TableB where colB1 = 0)
```

The issue is, the `colA1` does not exist in `TableB`.

So if I just run this

```
select colA1 
from TableB 
where colB1 = 0
```

Then SQL Server Management Studio will return an error:

> Invalid column name 'colA1'.

But if it is in the `where` cause, the first SQL can be executed as if where cause is always true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats because SQL Server first looks for the column in TableB, fails to find it, so then looks in TableA. If you fully qualify your column names (or use table aliases) you will get the error e.g.

```
select A.*
from TableA A
where A.colA1 in (
    select B.colA1
    from TableB B
    where B.colB1 = 0
);
```

Essentially your query is reduced to:

```
select *
from TableA
where colA1 in (colA1);
```

Thats why you should always fully qualify your table names, ideally through the use of a short, meaningful aliases.

Answer (score -1):

I was unable to replicate your problem. I tried it on my SQL Server and got an error

```
select *
from student.Paper
where PaperCode in (select PaperCodeXXX from student.Paper)
```

> Invalid column name 'PaperCodeXXX'.

I tried it on a different table and a non-existent table and got the same result

Comment: After reading the above comments I am able to replicate:

--PaperTypeCode is in Paper but not PaperOccurrence

select * 
from student.Paper 
where PaperCode in (select PaperTypeCode from student.PaperOccurrence)